# How to update a field value to an empty list [] using AWS AppSync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

Let's say I have a GraphQL schema:

```
type MyModel {
  canUpdate: [String]
}
```

If it already contains values, eg `["value1","value2"]` and I want to update to an empty list: `[]`, how do I achieve this?

When I use the AppSync console it only lets me enter a string:

[image]

But this just replaces `["value1","value2"]` with `["?"]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit the value to the right of the inputs panel (in the middle panel):

[image]

Update to:

[image]